# Getting last-child by class name through JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get hold of the last child of class `full-width`. It's a looping text with border-bottom. All I want is that the last child doesn't get the border. To make sure it works in IE8 too, I am doing it through JQuery:-

Somehow it doesn't work.

### JQuery

```
$(".solutions-section .field-items .field-item div:last-child").css("border-bottom","none");
```

### HTML

```
<div class="full-width info-block solutions-section">
    <div class="field field-name-field-solutions-area field-type-text-long field-label-hidden">
       <div class="field-items">
          <div class="field-item even" style="border-bottom-style: none;"><h2>A Para</h2>

              <div class="full-width solid-block">
                  <div class="alignleft onethird-width ">
                      <img border="0" src="sites/all/themes/ourbrand/images/image.png" width="120">
                  </div>
                  <div class="alignleft qtr-width small-text dark-grey">
                       Who is it for? All Text</div>
                  <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>

              </div>

              <div class="full-width solid-block">
                  <div class="alignleft onethird-width ">
                      <img border="0" src="sites/all/themes/ourbrand/images/image.png" width="120">
                  </div>
                  <div class="alignleft qtr-width small-text dark-grey">
                       Who is it for? All Text</div>
                  <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>

              </div>

</div></div></div></div>
```

Comment: `$(".solutions-section .field-items .field-item div:last").css("border-bottom","none");` - but with the given markup `last-child` should work

Comment: use `:last` instead of `last-child`

Comment: It doesn;t work unfortunately.

Comment: @Steve: can you share problem fiddle.

Comment: @ArunPJohny has right.Worked for me. Are you sure jquery library is available at your file of this example?

Answer (score 0):

I think ur selection not only select the child div only. It will take all the div contain in item-field class.

just add '>' before div maybe help.

```
$(".solutions-section .field-items .field-item > div:last").css("border-bottom","none")
```

example here http://jsfiddle.net/w6s6puLu/

Answer (score 0):

If I get your problem correctly then you can use :

```
$(".solutions-section .field-items .field-item div.full-width:last-child").css("border", "2px solid green");
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ua2g8d2y/5/)</kbd>

Just see if it helps!